# How can I send a .log file from one Debian to another Linux OS?

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I'm currently working on a project that involves a Honeypot which is generating events on a .log file. I want to send these events to a remote server. What is the easiest way to do this?

I've been doing some research and tried to do it with rsyslog using imfile but It's not working for me; I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way though.

This is what I added to my rsyslog.conf file on my client

```
    *.* @@ipaddress:514
    /etc/rsyslog.conf$
    $ModLoad imfile
    $InputFileName /var/log/conpot/conpot.log
    $InputFileTag CONPOT
    $InputFileSaverity Info
    $InputFileFacility local3
    $InputRunFileMonitor
    local3.* @@ipaddress:514
```

This is what I added to my rsyslog.conf file on my server

```
    module(load="imudp")
    input(type="imudp" port="514")
    module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")
    $template RemoteLogs, "/var/log/$HOSTNAMES%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
    *.* ?RemoteLogs
    & ~
```

That's all I have added to my conf files, what I'm I missing?

I expect to get all the events from ~/conpot.log to my rsyslog server but I do not seem to get them

Comment: `@@` means use tcp, so you should replace `imudp` by `imtcp`.

Comment: @meuh I totally missed that; now it's working. Thank you so much.